# Python Minesweeper Values Indexing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a program that generates a list of "minesweeper board" values. Each item in the list is either strings "0" or "BOMB" as of right now.

I've been trying to work on program efficiency, abstraction and decomposition, recursion etc. Obviously I could just hook in a *for* loop and move from there(which I've already done lol), but I want this to be able to work on a (semi)huge scale.

How would I be able to efficiently count the number of bombs in a cell from the given list?

```
class Sweeper:
    '''
    Sweeper(xin, yin) : xin = far right x int, yin = bottom y int
    0 
     |
    y|_____ 
      0   x 
    '''

    def __init__(self, xin, yin):
        '''generates values, number of mines and starts gears'''
        self.values = list("0" * xin * yin)
        #self.mines =  int(yin * xin ** 1.11 - yin * xin)
        self.genmines(self.mines)#Start Generation

    def genmines(self, amt):
        '''Generates Mines'''
        for ite in range(amt):
            self.values[random.randint(0, len(self.values) - 1)] = 'BOMB' 
    def getvalues(self):
        ######
Sweeper(9, 9).getvalues()
```

will output:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', 'BOMB', '0', 'BOMB', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', 'BOMB', 'BOMB', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0', '0', 'BOMB', 'BOMB', '0', '0', 'BOMB', '0', '0']
```

I have some equation ideas using the (x) variable that seem to work, but I have no idea how to implement them efficiently. Will elaborate on them if prompted in comments, as I feel like they'll just clog up the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
minelist = []
cols = 20
rows = 20
chanceofbomb = 10
for x in range(cols):
    xlist = []
    for y in range(rows):
        isBomb = randint(0,chanceofbomb)
        if isBomb == 0:
            xlist.append("Bomb!")
        else:
            xlist.append('0')
    minelist.append(xlist)
```

This will create a map for you.
You could access the map indexes with

```
minelist[requiredx][requiredy]
```

Example

```
canvas = Canvas(self.tk,width=400,height=400,bg="white")
canvas.pack()
color = "red"
for x in range(cols):
    for y in range(rows):
        if minelist[x][y] == "Bomb!":
            ##Place bomb. Going to place it in a Tkinter format
            canvas.create_rectangle(x*10,y*10,(x*10)+10,(y*10)+10,fill=color,width=0)
##Continue with code
```

Comment: Once I pick this apart I'm sure it's going to help loads cause from what I've seen so far it's giving me some good ideas. But how would I be able to turn the '0' into a '2' or a 'None' efficiently though? Would I  inevitably  have to iterate over every single point on the grid?

Answer (score 0):

```
def findValue(x, y):
    valueOfSpot = 0
    for xa in range(cols):
        for ya in range(rows):
            if abs(minelist[xa] - (x*10)) < 2 and abs(minelist[ya] - (y*10)) < 2:
                valueOfSpot += 1
    minelist[x][y] = valueOfSpot
```

This may make the process quicker.

```
for xb in range(cols):
    for yb in range(rows):
        findValue(xb, yb)
```

Comment: Sorry the if statement should be: if abs(minelist[xa] - (x*10)) == 1 and abs(minelist[ya] - (y*10)) == 1: else it would count itself

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)

Comment: Also, I forgot to add in an "if" statement to check for mines instead of just squares.